# candisplaybannerads jerks onto screen when ad loads

Tags: ios, objective-c, iad, candisplaybannerads

I saw a few posts on this but neither seemed to answer my issue...

I have a menu at the bottom of my view constrained to the bottom layout guide so that when an ad loads using

```
self.candisplaybannerads = true;
```

the menu moves up as well. In iOS7 this transition is smooth and the menu slides up as the banner slides up. But in iOS8 the menu pops up to the new location and then the banner slides up smooth. Has anyone else experience this or know how to fix it.
Thanks

Sample Project: https://github.com/jbestor/adTest (in the sample project neither iOS7 or iOS8 smoothly slides up).

Constraints for button menu:

```
//button1
[self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_button1 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing
                                                      relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view
                                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing multiplier:1.0 constant:0.0]];
[self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_button1 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                                      relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.bottomLayoutGuide
                                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom multiplier:1.0 constant:0.0]];
[self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_button1 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                                      relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:nil
                                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute multiplier:1.0 constant:50]];
[self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_button1 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                                      relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:nil
                                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute multiplier:1.0 constant:50]];

//button2
[self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_button2 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading
                                                      relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view
                                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading multiplier:1.0 constant:0.0]];
[self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_button2 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                                      relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.bottomLayoutGuide
                                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom multiplier:1.0 constant:0.0]];
[self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_button2 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                                      relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:nil
                                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute multiplier:1.0 constant:50]];
[self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_button2 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                                      relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:nil
                                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute multiplier:1.0 constant:50]];

//button3
[self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_button3 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading
                                                      relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view
                                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading multiplier:1.0 constant:0.0]];
[self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_button3 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                                      relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.bottomLayoutGuide
                                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom multiplier:1.0 constant:0.0]];
[self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_button3 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                                      relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:nil
                                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute multiplier:1.0 constant:self.view.frame.size.width]];
[self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_button3 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                                      relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:nil
                                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute multiplier:1.0 constant:50]];
```

Comment: Can you add the exact constraints of your menu to your question so I can recreate the problem?

Comment: @DanielStorm updated with constraints - thanks

Comment: I created a sample project here [https://github.com/jbestor/adTest](https://github.com/jbestor/adTest) but in the project the iOS7 and iOS8 simulator both demonstrate the non-smooth result.